# Reducing space between enumeration and item

Tags: enumerate, line-spacing, enumitem, line-numbering

Trying to modify an  R program that generates a PDF.  Here is the output it produces, I want to get rid of the space that is marked in yellow.

[image: Output produced - with space to be removed marked in yellos]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[20pt,fleqn,leqno]{extarticle}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[a5paper,top=1in,bottom=0.75in,left=0.75in,right=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol,xparse,bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop

\setlength\headsep{40pt}
%\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins

% multicols - fix for single column
\let\multicolmulticols\multicols
\let\endmulticolmulticols\endmulticols

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}
 {%
  \ifnum#1=1
    #2%
  \else % More than 1 column
    \multicolmulticols{#1}[#2]
  \fi
 }
 {%
  \ifnum#1=1
  \else % More than 1 column
    \endmulticolmulticols
  \fi
 }

% - end multicols fix
\begin{document}
\fontsize{ 40}{48}\begin{multicols}{1}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},before*=\small,leftmargin=*,itemsep=1.0cm, labelsep=0.5cm]
\item \scalebox{3}{  \quad \bf \opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {3}{2} \quad}
\item \scalebox{3}{  \quad \bf \opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {2}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{3}{  \quad \bf \opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {4}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{3}{  \quad \bf \opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {6}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{3}{  \quad \bf \opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {7}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{3}{  \quad \bf \opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {8}{1} \quad}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

ps: As the tex output is produced by a larger program (I have created a working sample out of the larger output) I have limited flexibility to modify the way the output is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that `scalebox` also scales by `3` the `quad` inserted at the beginning of each item? Furthermore, a scale factor of 3 is too big for this paper size. I had to reduce it to `2.2` and to remove the `\quad`s at the beginning.

I took the opportunity to slightly simplify your code. In particular, needless to load `color` since you load `xcolor`. Also note `\bf` has been deprecated for about 25 years. Use `\bfseries` instead.

```
\documentclass[20pt,fleqn,leqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[a5paper,top=1in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.25in, showframe]{geometry}% option showframe just to show the margins

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol,xparse,bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop

\setlength\headsep{40pt}

% multicols - fix for single column
\let\multicolmulticols\multicols
\let\endmulticolmulticols\endmulticols

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}
 {%
  \ifnum#1=1
    #2%
  \else % More than 1 column
    \multicolmulticols{#1}[#2]
  \fi
 }
 {%
  \ifnum#1=1
  \else % More than 1 column
    \endmulticolmulticols
  \fi
 }
% - end multicols fix

\begin{document}

\fontsize{ 40}{48}\begin{multicols}{1}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},font=\normalfont\small, leftmargin=*,itemsep=1.0cm, labelsep=0.4cm, before = \bfseries]
\item \scalebox{2.2}{\opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {3}{2} \quad}
\item \scalebox{2.2}{\opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {2}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{2.2}{\opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {4}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{2.2}{\opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {6}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{2.2}{\opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {7}{1} \quad}
\item \scalebox{2.2}{\opadd[style=text, voperation=center,resultstyle=\gobble,intermediarystyle=\hole,carryadd=false] {8}{1} \quad}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]